# Count the number of words in a string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I have a simple Google spreadsheet with a number of text strings. I just want the number of words contained in each cell. Is there an in-built Google spreadsheet function I may use?

Answer (score 10):

In Google Spreadsheets, I would do it a bit different.

### Formula

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, " "))
```

### Explained

The `SPLIT` function is only available in Google Spreadsheet and will split the cell's content on every space (`" "`). The `COUNT` function will simply count the instances.

The Excel formula gives the same answer, but a bit more laborious:

```
=LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Remark

See following answer on which formulae are unique to Google Spreadsheet:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44719/29140

Comment: For the most part this worked for me (in Google Sheets)... except empty cell returned 1.. So I changed it a little so that empty cells return 0: `=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, " "))-IF(A1 = "",1,0)`

Comment: We do something similar but it will not work when spaces are not the normal spaces character (e.g. tabs, etc). So I'd love to find a slightly clever way of counting words.

Comment: Hi Aldo, best is to simply ask your question here on Web Applications !!!

Answer (score 3):

Slight improvement to formula in [this other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/52024/88163) so in case that A1 is blank or if it has an empty string it will return zero.

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=0,0,COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," "))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **do this on a cell range** (i.e. `A1:A25`) you can use the formula above, where `CHAR(32)` is the space character `" "`

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(A1:A25&CHAR(32)));CHAR(32)))
```

This works with blank cells, except when initial cell is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Another:

`=COUNTA(SPLIT(TRIM(A1&" #")," "))-1`

This just appends a space and pound sign to the end of whatever's in the target cell, *including adding it to a null*, so there are never any errors throwing off the count. Then we're just subtracting that temporary "fake space" back out at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), 
 MMULT(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(LEN(A3:A), A3:A, ), " "))<>"", 1, 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(IFERROR(
 QUERY(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(LEN(A3:A), A3:A, ), " "))<>"", 1, 0), "limit 1", 0)))))^0), ))
```

[image: 0]

### ______________________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "[^\s]", ))+1, ))
```

[image: 0]